# How to create a shortcut to a folder in Unity, using c#?

Tags: unity, c#

My game saves screenshots in the persistent data path `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Screenshots");`. 
I would like to create a shortcut in my game directory, which leads to this screenshot location, using C#.

Multiple times I found solutions similar to [this one](https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/create-shortcut-programmatically-in-c/) (https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/create-shortcut-programmatically-in-c/), but this does not work for me. I find the reference "Windows Script Host Object Model", but when I try to add it, I get the following error: 
*"A reference to 'Windows  Script Host Object Model' could not be added. The type library wrapper tool 'tlbimp' cannot be found on this system. Please re-install Visual Studio."*

Of course I want to avoid to re-install anything.

Is there another or easier way? Or rather; how can I create a shortcut inside my game directory, that points to a folder in Unitys persistent data path, using C#?

Comment: [Searching this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+create+shortcut&searchOn=3) leads to [this answer that does not use the Script Host Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897700/3064164) - does that work for your needs?

Comment: If the persistent data path is deterministic for your needs (i.e. uses the AppData folder etc.) then you could, in theory, commit the shortcut as an asset to be included in game files.